# State not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am writing a react-redux code for a simple calculator. Here is my component file

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Calculator extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <div className="text-center">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button name='1' value='1' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('1')}>1</button>
                    <button name='2' value='2' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('2')}>2</button>
                    <button name='3' value='3' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('3')}>3</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button name='4' value='4' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('4')}>4</button>
                    <button name='5' value='5' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('5')}>5</button>
                    <button name='6' value='6' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('6')}>6</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button name='7' value='7' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('7')}>7</button>
                    <button name='8' value='8' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('8')}>8</button>
                    <button name='9' value='9' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('9')}>9</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button name='+' value='+' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('+')}>+</button>
                    <button name='0' value='0' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('0')}>0</button>
                    <button name='-' value='-' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('-')}>-</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button name='/' value='/' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('/')}>/</button>
                    <button name='evalu' value='evalu' onClick={()=>this.props.evaluation('=')}>=</button>
                    <button name='*' value='*' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('*')}>*</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button name='cler' value='cler' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('clear')}>clear</button>
                    <button name='bs' value='bs' onClick={()=>this.props.addition('bs')}>del</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

const matchStatestoProps = state =>{
    return {expression:state.expression}
}

const matchDispatchtoProps = dispatch =>{
    return {
        addition: (data)=> dispatch({type:'ADD',payload:data}),
        evaluation: ()=>dispatch({type:'EVAL'})
    }
}

export default connect(matchStatestoProps,matchDispatchtoProps)(Calculator);
```

Here is my reducer:

```
    const defaultState={
    expression:''
};

var rootReducer = (state=defaultState, {action,payload}) =>{
    switch (action){
        case 'ADD':
        return {expression:state.expression+payload};
        default: return defaultState;
    }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Now when I click a button it is firing an action , but the state is not getting updated. It is still empty. Could someone please help me in this?

Here is the screenshot of redux store:

[image]

Comment: also you are summing concating strings not summing anything '' + '1' = '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the action under the key `type` not the key `action` so instead of destructing your arguments like this:

```
var rootReducer = (state = defaultState, { action, payload }) =>{
```

You should do it like this

```
var rootReducer = (state = defaultState, { type, payload }) =>{
```

Then switch `type` instead of `action`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to take type from action object

```
var rootReducer = (state=defaultState,{type, payload}) =>{
    switch (type){
        case 'ADD':
        return {expression:state.expression+payload};
        default: return defaultState;
    }
}
```